# logstash convert string to date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I want to convert string to date in logstash.
I tried to do it with 2 solutions but it doesn't work.

1) with mutate/convert

```
grok {match => {"message" => '%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_date} - %{GREEDYDATA:key}:%INT:value}'}
mutate {convert => ["log_date", "date"]}
```

2) with date/target :

```
date {match => [ "value", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ZZZ"] target => "value"}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste an entry from your logs. And what type of logs it is?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your first try you dont have the datestring in a separate field. In this case I would recommend this:

> [Add extra value to field before sending to elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432232/add-extra-value-to-field-before-sending-to-elasticsearch/48438797#48438797)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers I found the solution with the date filter.

```
filter { grok {match => {"message" => '%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_date} - %{GREEDYDATA:key}:%INT:value}'}

date {
  match => [ "log_date", "ISO8601", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ZZZ" ]
  target => "log_date"
  locale => "en"
}
```